# Why won't Anbox run successfully on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS?

Tags: anbox

It mostly installed successfully per [these steps](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-android-apps-games-linux/), but when I try to run it, I get this screen and then it just disappears.

[image]

Comment: A good start would be to search "Anbox" here and review similar questions that have accepted solutions. If you continue to need more help with this, we will need more information than you've provided here. Include context and details so we know what exactly you've done so far. A link to a tutorial or guide is insufficient to tell us what you did or where things started to go wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.